# Face Recognition Prediction problem on real time streaming videos

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition, knn

For Face Recognition I am using ***KNN based approach*** as per [link](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition)

**Training dataset**

- Bollywood Actors: Total Actors 50 and for each actor 100 images are
  there
- Bollywood Actress: Total Actress 50 and for each actor 100 images
  are there

For Testing this model I am using **Real time Youtube Videos** and [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tac66nkcMvg&t=4s) of one of the video

With correct detection large number of misclassifications are also coming and as video length increases misclassifications are also increasing

**Result of Above video**

Correct detection

1. Boman_Irani
2. Amitabh_Bachchan

Incorrect detection

- Sridevi
- Virender _Sehwag
- Nishant _Chaturvedi
- Mausam _Khatri
- Uttam _Kumar

**IS THERE ANY WAY TO REDUCE/REMOVE THIS WRONG DETECTION**

Update:

I've tried these two examples.

1. https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py
2. https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: 1. https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet  2.https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py

Comment: I have tried these two links

Comment: Add more details in question itself instead of comment.